# Pass multiple inputs into Map State in AWS Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am trying to use AWS Step Functions to trigger operations many S3 files via Lambda.  To do this I am invoking a step function with an input that has a base S3 key of the file and part numbers each file (each parallel iteration would operate on a different S3 file).  The input looks something like

```json
    {
      "job-spec": {
        "base_file_name": "some_s3_key-",
        "part_array": [
          "part-0000.tsv",
          "part-0001.tsv",
          "part-0002.tsv", ...
        ]
      }
    }
```

My Step function is very simple, takes that input and maps it out, however I can't seem to get both the file and the array as input to my lambda.  Here is my step function definition

```json
    {
      "Comment": "An example of the Amazon States Language using a map state to process elements of an array with a max concurrency of 2.",
      "StartAt": "Map",
      "States": {
        "Map": {
          "Type": "Map",
          "ItemsPath": "$.job-spec",
          "ResultPath": "$.part_array",
          "MaxConcurrency": 2,
          "Next": "Final State",
          "Iterator": {
            "StartAt": "My Stage",
            "States": {
              "My Stage": {
                "Type": "Task",
                "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::lambda:invoke",
                "Parameters": {
                  "FunctionName": "arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<>:function:some-lambda:$LATEST",
                  "Payload": {
                    "Input.$": "$.part_array"
                  }
                },
                "End": true
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "Final State": {
          "Type": "Pass",
          "End": true
        }
      }
    }
```

As written above it complains that that `job-spec` is not an array for the `ItemsPath`.  If I change that to `$.job-spec.array` I get the `array` I'm looking for in my lambda but the base `key` is missing.

Essentially I want each python lambda to get the base file key and one entry from the array to stitch together the complete file name. I can't just put the complete file names in the array due to the limit limit of how much data I can pass around in Step Functions and that also seems like a waste of data

It looks like the `Parameters` value can be used for this but I can't quite get the syntax right

Comment: Looks like there is now a "new" Map State mode overcoming the limitation described in this question. It is the Distributed processing mode of Step Functions Map State : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/concepts-inline-vs-distributed-map.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Was able to finally get the syntax right.

```json
"ItemsPath": "$.job-spec.part_array",
"Parameters": {
  "part_name.$": "$$.Map.Item.Value",
  "base_file_name.$": "$.job-spec.base_file_name"
},
```

It seems that `Parameters` can be used to create custom inputs for each stage.  The `$$` is accessing the context of the stage and not the actual input.  It appears that `ItemsPath` takes the array and puts it into a context which can be used later.

**UPDATE** Here is some [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html) showing this being used from the comments below

Comment: Awesome, thank you! In my case, I wanted to pass in a parameter (s3 bucket name) generated in a separate resource. Using the `$$.Map.Item.Value` and `.$` was key for pairing the two when using Input, and then normal `Key: Ref! MyResource` in the external parameter.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share a blog post or documentation on this, the AWS documentation is pretty thin on the details of this rather complicated means of passing data between states. In my case, I have one SF calling another, and need to pass an array of input to SF 2's Map state, so that each element of the array of input can be passed as a named parameter to a Glue job.

Comment: Acccess to $$.Map.Item.Value is demonstrated, but not very thoroughly explained, in the SF documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-map-state.html

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/input-output-contextobject.html#contextobject-map

Answer (score 1):

This was a real PITA. Here is an example with `AWS CDK`:

```js
const mapBlock = new sfn.Map(this, "processLoop", {

// Pick your array path
  itemsPath: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.uploadedFiles"),

// Use this to manipulate data going into each loop
  parameters: {

// Now we can use $$.Map.Item.Value to get the current item value
    item: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$$.Map.Item.Value"),

// Any additional info you want from the map block input
    collection: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.collectionName"),
    bucket: sfn.JsonPath.stringAt("$.bucket"),
  },
});
```